# How to get dpi of an image cropped with Python? Tesseract --dpi parameter

Tags: opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract, dpi, pymupdf

My code opens a pdf, converts the first page to an image, then cuts rectangles out of this image by coordinates and extracts text from each cropped rectangle using Tesseract.

I discovered that in some cases for larger images OCR performs much worse than in other cases.

After playing around with Tesseract in the command line, I also discovered that for some images Tesseract estimates the resolution itself which affects the result.

I also played around with the --dpi parameter. For some images the best results were obtained with --dpi 1800, for some with --dpi 300.
I'm looking for a way to set the dpi for my images before extracting text or a way to find the dpi of my images.

I also tried to use `pix.set_dpi()` and `get_pixmap(dpi = ..)` and that didn't improve anything. I would be thankful for any suggestions

Here is the code I use:

```
        page = doc.load_page(0)
        page_size = page.rect
        zoom = 3
        mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
        pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)
        img_data = pix.samples
        img_array = np.frombuffer(img_data, dtype=np.uint8)
        img_array = img_array.reshape(pix.height, pix.width, pix.n)
        img = cv.cvtColor(img_array, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                    
        #...
        k=0
        result_dict = {}
        for i, rect in enumerate(rectangles):
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = rect
            roi = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            k+=1
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, lang="eng+deu")
```

Comment: You don't say it, but you obviously are using PyMuPDF. This offers **_(1)_** a direct way to interact with Tesseract (without additional packages), and **_(2)_** to **_selectively_** OCR a page - i.e. only OCR any images on it and accept standard text. Furthermore, you can directly specify the DPI if you want to OCR the full page (a DPI specification for the images on the page make no sense, because these are "baked-in"). Overall, your code can be made much more concise and efficient. I am going to sketch a snippet further down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only OCR a region of a PDF page like this:

```py
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")
page = doc[pno]  # 0-based page number
rect = fitz.Rect(x0, y0, x1, y1)  # an area on the page
pix = page.get_pixmap(clip=rect, dpi=150)

# make a 1-page temp PDF from the area and OCR it
ocr = fitz.open("pdf", pix.pdfocr_tobytes())  # 1-page temp PDF
ocrpage = ocr[0]
text = ocrpage.get_text()  # OCRed text
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

OCR a PDF page using PyMuPDF with its Tesseract interface.

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")  # some PDF (or any other supported file type!)
page = doc[0]  # load page via page number

# OCR images parts of the page
tp = page.get_textpage_ocr(flags=3, language='eng', dpi=72, full=False, tessdata=None)

text = page.get_text()
```

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

Comment: Thank you, that's new for me. But the actual thing here is that I don't need the full text from the whole page of a PDF or from images this page contains. I need to get text from specific rectangle regions of pdf that are determined by coordinates. I'm also aware of tools like pdfminer.six, but it's not really reliable, as I want to also extract texts from the scan, I don't want to deal with text boxes or text lines for a variety of reasons, etc.

Comment: as an alternative to the previous post, you can also "take a picture" from a page's region at desired DPI and OCR that only with a few lines of code- see below.